# unix condition checking!

Tags: unix, conditional-statements

what condition is being checked below?

if [[ ! -s ${FILE} || -z ${FILE} ]]

(here $FILE is a data file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the manpage for `test(1)`.  $FILE either does not exist, has zero size, or is an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
! -s ${FILE}
```

checks if file exists and is not empty

```
-z ${FILE}
```

checks if the FILE string length is zero